# Rsyslog - How can I parse json message and use as variable in if condition

Tags: json, logging, haproxy, rsyslog

My application is sending log which is json-formatted (nested) to rsyslog via UDP like below.

```json
{"http": {"status_code": 400}}
```

I want to parse this log and use property as a variable in if condition like in rsyslog conf.

```
if ($!http!status_code >= 400) then {
    /var/log/haproxy/haproxy-traffic-error.log
    stop
}
```

Is this possible? This issue is making me crazy now.
I have looked for many articles about `mmjsonparse`, `mmnormalize` and etc...

Comment: Please add and example of an entire log message you receive. Depending on the structure of the logs, you'll have to a different approach. || Are your logs CEE enhanced?